# How do you put custom markup in a sitecore sc field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I need to add some custom markup for the `sc:Image` field to enchance SEO. This markup is not a property of the field, so from codebehind, I tried something like this:

```cs
slideImage.Attributes.Add("ControlType", "C4Image");
slideImage.Attributes.Add("rel", relString);
```

But this isn't working, and I see nothing in the rendered output. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create you own class inheriting from the `Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Image` and override it like this:

```
namespace My.Assembly.Namespace
{
    public class MyImage : Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Image
    {
        public virtual string RelAttribute { get; set; }

        protected override void PopulateParameters(Sitecore.Collections.SafeDictionary<string> parameters)
        {
            base.PopulateParameters(parameters);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(RelAttribute))
            {
                parameters.Add("rel", RelAttribute);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then register the namespace and use the `MyImage` class:

```
<%@ Register tagPrefix="my" namespace="My.Assembly.Namespace" assembly="My.Assembly" %>

<my:MyImage runat="server" RelAttribute="reltest" Field="logo"/>
```

You can use all the standard attributes from `sc:Image` on the `my:MyImage` as well.
The code will generate `img` tag with rel `<img rel="reltest" src="logo.jpg" ... />`.

You can easily extend the code above to support `ControlType` attribute as well.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the "Parameters" property for setting extra properties on both the  and  control.

You can to it like this :

```
<sc:FieldRenderer ID="PageImage" runat="server" FieldName="ContentImage" Parameters="ControlType=C4Image&rel=relString" />
<sc:Image ID="SCPageImage" runat="server" Field="ContentImage" Parameters="ControlType=C4Image&rel=relString" />
```

That will be rendered like this :

```
<img width="1232" height="637" controltype="C4Image" rel="relString" alt="" src="~/media/Images/DEMO backgrounds/background2.ashx">
```

Comment: So much ways to do one thing in Sitecore :)

Comment: But, I thought that you want to setup properties through C#? Over here you are setting up statically.

Comment: Yes - but you can do it from c# as well byt setting the .Parameters property - PageImage.Parameters = "blah:

Answer (score -2):

For screnario's like this, I'd ditch the FieldRenderers and revert to a regular html tag with databinding to the (the url of the) image.
The LinkManager is your friend here.